# How to find and delete a Git repository created using Android-Studio on windows?

Tags: windows, git, android-studio

I created A git repository on windows 7 using Android-Studio and I want to delete it. I can't find the .git repository with `dir` in `cmd` nor with `Get-ChilItems` in power-shell, in the directory or anywhere else on windows.

Where is it?
How can I delete it?

Comment: It's hidden. Modify your Windows Explorer options to show hidden files. From the Windows Explorer menu (press Alt to show it), go to Folder Options > View and check the "Hidden Files and Folders" settings

Comment: I guess that is what worked for me.

Comment: Why didn't it appear on cmd?

Comment: please enter an answer and I will endorse it

Answer (score 2):

The `.git` folder is created as a hidden folder. You can view hidden folders by going to Windows Explorer's menu (press Alt if it doesn't appear) and select Tools > Folder Options > View. In the checklist, select `Show Hidden files and folders`.

Hidden files and folders will appear now, with dimmed icons

Comment: Please add that if you open a terminal as administrator "root" then the directories are visible e.g right click on powershell and run as administrator.